# Why is my Left Not pulling all the dates even though they exist on the other table SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table without dates and wish to join on the table with dates.I am doing a  left join on id and bn_number. The id can have more than one dates , i obviously want the latest date from the other tables as it has more than one date for each id. i am not sure how to get all the dates at least then i can be able to choose the latest one.

```
select Reg_Property_id,a.Bnd_nbr,account_balance,abs(account_balanc‌​e) as Bond_Balance,a.Bnd_regDate 
into #Jan2014ValidFin 
from #Jan2014Valid aa 
left join Pr_analytics..bond a 
    on aa.Reg_Property_id=a.Prop_id 
    and aa.bnd_nbr=a.Bnd_nbr 
where aa.reg_property_id is not null
```

SQL

Please assist.

Comment: You need to post your current working query for anyone to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Comment: select Reg_Property_id,a.Bnd_nbr,account_balance,abs(account_balance) as Bond_Balance,a.Bnd_regDate 
into #Jan2014ValidFin
from #Jan2014Valid aa
left join Pr_analytics..bond  a on aa.Reg_Property_id=a.Prop_id  and aa.bnd_nbr=a.Bnd_nbr 
where aa.reg_property_id is not null

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: And what do you get? What is wrong with result you get?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to get the most recent date:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
    SELECT a.cols, b.cols, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.colID1,b.colID2 ORDER BY b.theDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col1
        AND a.col2 = b.col2
) c
WHERE c.rn = 1
```

Comment: A little correction. There shouldn't be comma before ORDER keyword.

Comment: @MarekVitek Sorry about that. Since it should have been partitioned by 2 columns, apparently my brain ran faster than my fingers.

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=88285aceff9ab07837750c355e2953da  <<< This will include a Reg_Property_ID that doesn't have a Bond associated with it. I'm assuming this is what you where looking for.

Comment: let me make the changes and see

Comment: SELECT c.* into #Jan2014ValidFin_2 
FROM (
    SELECT a.Reg_Property_id,a.Bnd_nbr,a.account_balance,abs(a.account_balance) as Bond_Balance,b.Bnd_regDate, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Reg_Property_id,b.Prop_id ORDER BY b.Bnd_regDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM #Jan2014Valid a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pr_analytics..bond b ON a.Reg_id = b.Pro_id AND a.Bnd_nbr = b.Bnd_nbr
 where a.reg_property_id is not null 
) c
WHERE c.rn = 1


select count(*) from #Jan2014ValidFin_2 where Bnd_regDate is null --210 777

Comment: @Mzila What is the "210 777"?  Is that 210,777 rows that returned with no `Bnd_Reg_Date`?  Do most `Reg_Property_ID`s not have a `Bnd_RegDate`? If you want to only show records that only have a `Bnd_RegDate`, you should be able to change the WHERE in your windowed sub-select to `WHERE a.Bnd_RegDate IS NOT NULL`. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b8058e8e41a97cb733e122a65437d2cc

Comment: yes 210 777 null bnd_regdate. The reason i am worried about this is that when i actually look for the bnd_regdate i find them on the left joined table.

Comment: i don't think eliminating them solves the issue. i just can't help but wonder why it's not helping

Comment: @Mzila The corrected fiddle should include only records that have a Reg_Property_ID and Bnd_Nbr in Jan2014Valid that matches a record in PR_Analytics.dbo.Bond that doesn't have a Bnd_RegDate.

Comment: did i code it correctly ? i posted it , please have a look. reg_property_id is from the first table

Comment: So do you need ALL `Reg_Property_IDs`/`Bnd_Nbr` from `Jan2014Valid`, even if they don't have a Bond in PR_Analytics..Bond?

Comment: SELECT c.* into #Jan2014ValidFin_2 -- select * from #Jan2014ValidFin_2  drop table #Jan2014ValidFin_2
FROM (
    SELECT a.Reg_Property_id,a.Bnd_nbr,a.account_balance,abs(a.account_balance) as Bond_Balance,b.Bnd_regDate, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Reg_Property_id,b.Prop_id ORDER BY b.Bnd_regDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM #Jan2014Valid a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pr_analyticsall..bondpropertytransfer b ON a.Reg_Property_id = b.Prop_id AND a.Bnd_nbr = b.Bnd_nbr
 where a.reg_property_id is not null 
 order by 5
) c
WHERE c.rn = 1

Comment: Look at the query in http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b8058e8e41a97cb733e122a65437d2cc

Comment: Also, re above: the `order by 5` can be overridden by the outer select, so it's really not necessarily doing what you think it's doing. And rather than say `5`, explicitly name the column you're sorting on. That way if your SELECT ever changes, you don't have to worry about that ORDER.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `group by` should do the trick:

```
SELECT
   Reg_Property_id  --  What table is this from?
  ,a.Bnd_nbr
  ,account_balance  --  What table is this from?
  ,abs(account_balance) as Bond_Balance  --  What table is this from?
  ,max(a.Bnd_regDate)   as Bnd_regDate
 into #Jan2014ValidFin 
 from #Jan2014Valid aa 
  left join Pr_analytics..bond a 
   on aa.Reg_Property_id = a.Prop_id 
    and aa.bnd_nbr = a.Bnd_nbr 
 where aa.reg_property_id is not null
 group by
   Reg_Property_id
  ,a.Bnd_nbr
  ,account_balance
  ,abs(account_balance)
```

Note that if there are no dates (a.Bnd_regDate), you will get NULL

Note also that if any of the values marked "what table is this from" are found in #Jan2014Valid, you will need to either aggregate them (max, sum, etc.) or include them in the group by clause--I can't tell which, from the information provided.

Comment: total data is 609169
after removing the invalid account balance is 521851 

this is the merging step 

code asnwer #1 
has 302525 , this exlude the null dates from the posted code 
remember some of these dates actually exists since i manually double checked from the other table by 
select dates from the null dates using the null dates id. 

code asnwer #2 
has 513301 records after merging but still has 210777 null dates

Comment: Sorry, but without access to the data you are referring to, I can't follow along with the problem you are describing.